# Xamarin Studio c# null propagating operator

Tags: c#, nullable, xamarin-studio, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

Before filling a bug case about Xamarin Studio I wanted to ask your opinion

```
public class Class1
{
    public int AProp { get; set; }
}
```

Considering this simple scenario

```
Class1 c;
var aProp = c?.AProp;
```

Shouldn't `aProp` be inferred as an `int?` instance as it is in c#-6.0 on Visual Studio 2015+? Because actually it is not, it is inferred as a plain `int` instead.

Xamarin Studio is not complaining about the operator, but it's not recognizing `aProp` as a nullable type hence complaining about `.HasValue` property evaluation for example; not just with the Intellisense but what is worse at compile time

Am I missing something or is it just my IDE?

**EDIT**:
Acutally I just found out I can use it in a null-coalescence check, even if the inferred type is really actually `int`!!
What a mix! XD

Comment: Can you show the code where you're using `HasValue`?

Comment: Just for curiosity, what *is* the type?

Comment: @rory.ap The most simple you can immagine... just put the class in a namespace, add any method within it, call those second 2 lines and add something like `if (aProp.HasValue) { }`. Result: compile error `'int' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' [...]`

Comment: @Stefan What do you mean? You see it in the class the prop is an `int` and with the null-propagating operator should be inferred as an `int?` but it is not.

Comment: Well... never mind. To explain: you said it should be `int?`, but it isn't. So, what is it then? I assume it's interpreted as `int`. I didn't saw you mentioned this explicitly, (although in your comment you do).

Comment: @Stefan ups... you right, I will add it in the post. Thanks for pointing!

Comment: Both Xamarin Studio version 6.3 build 863 and VS2017 infer c?.AProp as an int?

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin `int int?` Sorry I didn't understand what you meant

Comment: Yes that was a typo.  I fixed my comment

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin Uh... something fishy's going on... my simplification is not able to reproduce the issue in my use case. Further investigating.....

Comment: Ok I got it, my bad, i simplified a bit too much and lost pieces in the process (as per my usual). Actually in the if condition I wasn't using the `aProp` evaluation but the expression itself `if (c?.AProp.HasValue) { }`. @rory.ap smelled it miles away, hence his first comment that I'm now understanding. In this usage the null propagating operator is kicking late: the `AProp` evaluation comes first as rigthly plain `int`. In other words it's missing brackets: `if ((c?.AProp).HasValue) { }`

Comment: @rory.ap Bulls eye! You smelled that I was checking the value with the property accessor itself like so: `if (c?.AProp.HasValue) { }` isn't it so? And you were right and it needs brackets before the `.HasValue`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code in a new Console Application compiled by Visual Studio and it is working fine:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Foo foo = new Foo(); //same result with Foo foo = null;

    var baz = foo?.Bar;
    if (baz.HasValue) //Expected Error here, but compiles fine
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So it is definitive a bug. You should open a new Issue at the Bug tracker of Xamarin Studio.

Comment: Thanks, but the bug is actually in my head! XD As you can see in my last comments for the OP

Comment: Alright. I would go into Hospital or to the pest exterminator then  Bugs in the head are not always healthy 

Comment: lol 04.35 here of a boiling hot afternoon with broken AC ... I guess I just have to come to terms with them XD